# Magento 2 : Error when opening backup in admin menu

Tags: magento-2.1, backup

On version 2.1.12 when I click on backups in the admin menu I get the below

> There has been an error processing your request Object DOMDocument
>   should be created.

In the logs I see this.

> [2018-03-24 12:28:33] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Declaration of
>   Magento\Backup\Model\Backup\Interceptor::getFile() should be
>   compatible with & Magento\Backup\Model\Backup::getFile() in
>   /home/staging/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Backup/Model/Backup/Interceptor.php
>   on line 7 [] []

I have googled but cant find anything with this issue, has anyone ever seen this before? Seems to be the only admin menu doing this. have deleted var/cache, page_cache, generation and view_processed and deployed static files but no fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and compiling di resolved it in my case.So execute following commands ;

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Hope it solves your issue.